# Book about a painter that can bring his paintings to life

Tags: story-identification

I've been looking for this book, for about 3 years, since I saw it in Barnes & Noble and forgot the name. It's about a painter/painter's apprentice who can bring his paintings to life and he doesn't know how to control/stop them. It was a hard cover 3, or so, years ago and it was a beautiful rich cover. I've struck out on everything that looks similar.

Comment: There is a whole section on this trope.  http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ArtInitiatesLife

Comment: Penny Crayon ;)

Comment: Given that paintings coming back to life are a very common trope, we need more details to pinpoint this work. Was the book new when you saw it? Was it originally in English? What did the cover depict? Did you read the book or just the cover blurb? What else can you remember about the plot?

Comment: @saturnseye - Squiglet; http://www.bbc.co.uk/cbeebies/get-squiggling

Comment: I think what you are looking for is Memory and Dream by Charles de Lint. I found your question and was hoping for an answer but found none. I decided to check through my old college emails and found it from an old email I got from my prof (it was a reading assignment). I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

It is not an entire book *per se*, but the stories by [Diana L. Paxson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diana_L._Paxson) about Lalo the Limner from the *[Thieves' World (aka Sanctuary)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thieves%27_World)* anthologies of collaboratively world-built short stories fits that bill:

- Painter discovers his works come to life (sometimes by drawing him into the works, sometimes by the works stepping out of the canvas).
- Hijinks ensue when he starts painting deities.
- He cannot really get ahold of and "own" his gift... he's a small character with a talent that is far too big for him.

Answer (score 2):

#### Given your time frame I am going to suggest the recent release of the [Imager Portfolio by L.E. Modesitt Jr](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0765320347).

[image]

> Imager is the beginning of a whole new fantasy in a whole new magical world from the bestselling creator of Recluce. Although Rhennthyl is the son of a leading wool merchant in L’Excelsis, the capital of Solidar, the most powerful nation on Terahnar, he has spent years becoming a journeyman artist and is skilled and diligent enough to be considered for the status of master artisan—in another two years. Then, in a single moment, his entire life is transformed when his master patron is killed in a flash fire, and Rhenn discovers he is an imager—one of the few in the entire world of Terahnar who can visualize things and make them real.
>
> He must leave his family and join the Collegium of Imagisle.  Imagers live separately from the rest of society because of their abilities (they can do accidental magic even while asleep), and because they are both feared and vulnerable. In this new life, Rhenn discovers that all too many of the “truths” he knew were nothing of the sort. Every day brings a new threat to his life.  He makes a powerful enemy while righting a wrong, and begins to learn to do magic in secret.
>
> Imager is the innovative and enchanting opening of an involving new fantasy story.
> Hardcover, 432 pages; Published March 17th 2009 by Tor Books