# Fantasy novel about an artist who can bring paintings to life

Tags: story-identification, magic

I am looking for a novel about a painter who does fantasy cover art for book. It is set in modern day. NOT a high fantasy style. He discovers that he can bring his paintings to life, enter the worlds of his paintings and take things out of them. The artists brings a lava nymph from one of his painting to life. His rival also has the ability and has a tell tale orange cast to all his paintings. I read this book in the late 90s. I think the cover was of a man climbing into a painting. The rooms was cluttered with painting supplies. He had a shocked look on his face.

Comment: When did you read it? And you might want to check out [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/21267) to see if it helps jog your memory.

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/70614/book-about-a-painter-that-can-bring-his-paintings-to-life