# Book about artist who can bring drawings to life

Tags: story-identification, books, magic

> I am looking for a novel about a painter who does fantasy cover art for book. It is set in modern day. NOT a high fantasy style. He discovers that he can bring his paintings to life, enter the worlds of his paintings and take things out of them. The artists brings a lava nymph from one of his painting to life. His rival also has the ability and has a tell tale orange cast to all his paintings. I read this book in the late 90s. I think the cover was of a man climbing into a painting. The rooms was cluttered with painting supplies. He had a shocked look on his face.

[The above query](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/188171/fantasy-novel-about-an-artist-who-can-bring-paintings-to-life) was posted by Inirba six years ago. It was not answered. I am also looking for this book. I have additional information and remember the plot of the story. Site rules will not let me add this additional information to the bottom of Inirba's post as I am a new user to I am posting this as a new query.

Plot summary:
The main character is a very talented but struggling artist. He is drawing a sketch of a nymph when it moves on the paper. He initially thinks he is going crazy.

He mentions this to his “friend” who is a passable artist but inexplicably rich and successful. Not long after he does this two people out of mythology a Greek man and and Amazon women show up at the main character’s home overpower him then pull out painting of demons.

The main character feels himself being pushed into the painting of hell where he knows he would die and in desperation somehow manages to instead magically jump into one of his own nearby paintings which happens to be a volcano he nearly falls into.

The “friend” has the power to bring drawings to life and pull them out of paintings the main character is developing the same abilities so is now a threat.

The finale of the book is a giant battle where both sides pull out monsters and magical items from paintings in giant showdown. The final showdown involves the main character summoning a giant spider, the antagonist summoning a giant mech that kills the spider. The main character summoning a "superman" type hero that destroys the mech, and the antagonist killing the "superman" with a powerful magic sword. The main character prevails despite being the weaker painting mage because he staged a distraction and tricked the antagonist into a painting that resembled the real world without him realizing. This gave him an advantage as he could summon creations without getting tired.